# How to load index file in Gatsby project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, gatsby

I'm porting my app from Create React App to Gatsby and I had some errors when I run gatsby build.

I believe I'm making a mistake in the setup of gatsby's index.js file

This was the `src/index.js` page and now I migrate to `src/pages/index.js`
I put the wrapRootElement, but I keep having error.

```
import Store from './store';

someSetup();

export const wrapRootElement = () => {
  return (
    (
      <Errors>
        <>
          <HtmlHead
            title={`${getPageTitle()}`}
          />
          <Provider store={Store}>
            <Intl>
              <Router />
            </Intl>
          </Provider>
        </>
      </Errors>
    ),
    document.querySelector('#app')
  );
};
```

Does anyone know what I'm wrong, if that's how I should load the index, since it worked in create react app?

The error I get is very generic: throw Error("Element type is invalid").

Check the render method of 'PageRenderer'.

Answer (score 0):

If the snippet you've provided is the home page should be capitalized, as any other React Component. Simply:

```
const IndexPage = (props) => {

  return <div>I'm your homepage</div>

}
```

Pasting the dummy snippet in your `index.js` file should work alone.

Regarding your `wrapRootElement`, I guess you mean the dual browser-SSR API. If you want to add your custom wrapping element, you'll need to add the following in **both** `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js` files, since it's a shared API.

```
const React = require("react")
const { Provider } = require("react-redux")

const createStore = require("./src/state/createStore")
const store = createStore()

exports.wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {element}
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

In this case, I'm using the Redux store. `element`, in this example, stands for the React Element built by Gatsby, so you are wrapping the provider of the state in each element of the page. Tweak it as you wish.

More information:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#wrapRootElement
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapRootElement